# accessing a non-static member error while using form/controls from static method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, static

In a project of mine I have code like the following in a class I've written named KeyboardHook...

```
    private static IntPtr keyboardHookId = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            //update UI here...
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    }
```

I'd like to update the UI with a statement like

```
    Form1.label1.Text = vkCode.ToString();
```

...but this causes a problem for the C# compiler; namely accessing a non-static member.
I need to create a reference to a Form1 object,ie.

```
            Application.Run(new Form1());
```

What to do?

Comment: Why not make the function non-`static`? This seems like an instance method, not a `static` one.

Answer (score -2):

In the SolutionExplorer open Program.cs and change the code there like the following

```
    static class Program
{
    public static Form1 mainForm = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        mainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

Here an instance of the Form1 class is created and started by the **Application.Run** command. Note that mainForm is initialized to **null** in Line 3 and not:

```
public static Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
```

This is because the **Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault()** method must be called before the first **IWin32Window** object is created in the application, or an **InvalidOperationException** will be thrown.